# Left hand side exponent

Tags: symbols

Please, how do I type this 2 inclusions:

[image]

? Note that the first inclusion has \chi form the
 **left**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use empty nucleus:

```
$^{\chi>\!}\lambda\subseteq I \subseteq {^{\chi\leq\!}}\lambda$
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `\prescript` command from `mathtools`:

```
\[ \prescript{\chi>\!}{}{\lambda}\subseteq I \subseteq \prescript{\chi\leq\!}{}{\lambda} \]%
```

[image]

Other possibilities: with the `leftidx`or `fouridx` packages.

Comment: Please see my Answer which is in fact a question.